# Vscode extension color settings will overwrite settings.json color settings, how to solve it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am using vscode and have some syntax highlight color customization in `settings.json`, which works great for other languages except Ruby. Because I installed `ruby on rails` extension, which has its own syntax highlight color settings.

When I open a Ruby file, the syntax highlight is at first my own customization, after about half second it becomes the syntax highlight from ruby on rails extension. So I believe that the rails extension overwrite my own customized color settings, I assert that the color loading order is: blank => `settings.json` => extension customization.

I wonder if there is any way to make my own color customization overwrite extensions' color settings? Such as make the loading order like this: blank => extension customization => `settings.json`.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's semantic highlight. Semantic highlight always apply it with delay.
You can disable it with writing this on settings.json.

```json
    "[ruby]": {
        "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false
    },
```